# SQL and ArcGIS data querying: what's the difference?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, sql, query, spatial-query

I am wondering if the language used by ArcGIS for data querying (e.g., search by attribute) is part of the SQL language, or to what extent there is a connection between the two (and where does it come from)?

Answer (score 4):

I'm having difficulty with the classification of "search by attribute" as a "language". To understand an answer to this startlingly broad question requires understanding of the meanings of a number of computer terms, including: Application software, [programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language), data format, user interface, and access paradigm.

ArcGIS is [application software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software).  It has a long history and supports [scores of different data formats](http://www.esri.com/library/fliers/pdfs/data-interop-formats.pdf).  Some of those data formats include relational databases (a different kind of application software), most of which support a common query syntax known a [Structured Query Language (SQL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL).

The Select By Attributes *tool* is a component in the ArcMap application [user interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface).
[image: Select By Attributes from Help]

It needs to support **all** the formats supported by ArcGIS.  This is accomplished by the [ArcObjects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArcObjects) development environment (in which ArcGIS is written) by organizing data sources into [code libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)) that support each data format, then providing a common set of [interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(computing)) to interact with those formats (get list of fields, get datatype of field, get list of unique values in field, ...)  In software development terms, this is known as *information hiding* -- the application doesn't need to care what the format needs to do to support a query, just that the component tasked with that support doesn't return an error message when asked to do it.

The code libraries for data sources which support SQL delegate the query expression evaluation to an actual SQL query.  Furthermore, for data sources where the geometry is stored in the database, the actual draw requests will include an SQL expression fragment which restricts results to those whose extent overlap the current draw window (but it is important to note that the code module which is responsible for actually drawing to the computer canvas still has the ultimate responsibility of making sure the feature does reside within the viewfield).

In summary, ArcGIS utilizes SQL in data sources that support SQL, and may utilize something that *looks* like SQL for data sources that aren't technically SQL-compliant (like shapefiles and file geodatabase), just because SQL is a standard [paradigm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradigm) in information technology.